# Error when adding ORDER BY in Select Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct

```
select 
    distinct on (productid)p.product,
    pb.productid, 
    pb.mrp,
    pb.ptr,
    pb.ssr,
    pt.patent
from  prod_batch pb
    inner Join  prod_patent pt using(patentid) 
    inner Join  prods p using(productid)  
where(qty - iqty) > 0
```

this selects returns correctly and getting what actually I want.!
When am adding an `ORDER BY` in the above *select* to sort according to the `product`'s name 
 I used to write like this..

```
select 
    distinct on (productid)p.product,
    pb.productid, 
    pb.mrp,
    pb.ptr,
    pb.ssr,
    pt.patent
from  prod_batch pb
    inner Join  prod_patent pt using(patentid) 
    inner Join  prods p using(productid)  
where(qty - iqty) > 0 
order by 
    product -- this is my column name to order by
```

Getting error while executing this

> ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY
>   expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

Choice - 1

```
select * from (
select 
    distinct on (productid)p.product,
    pb.productid, 
    pb.mrp,
    pb.ptr,
    pb.ssr,
    pt.patent
from  prod_batch pb
    inner Join  prod_patent pt using(patentid) 
    inner Join  prods p using(productid)  
where(qty - iqty) > 0 
order by 
    product
) t order by product
```

---

Choice - 2

```
With cte as (
select 
        distinct on (productid)p.product,
        pb.productid, 
        pb.mrp,
        pb.ptr,
        pb.ssr,
        pt.patent
    from  prod_batch pb
        inner Join  prod_patent pt using(patentid) 
        inner Join  prods p using(productid)  
    where(qty - iqty) > 0 

) select * from cte order by product
```

---

Choice - 3

Just make your select into a view

```
create or replace view pro_details as 
select 
    distinct on (productid)p.product,
    pb.productid, 
    pb.mrp,
    pb.ptr,
    pb.ssr,
    pt.patent
from  prod_batch pb
    inner Join  prod_patent pt using(patentid) 
    inner Join  prods p using(productid)  
where(qty - iqty) > 0
```

USAGE : `select * from pro_details order by product`

Comment: am going with option 3

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. [...] Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first. [...] The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s).

Try following

```
select 
     distinct on (productid)p.product,
     pb.productid, 
     pb.mrp,
     pb.ptr,
     pb.ssr,
     pt.patent
from  prod_batch pb
inner Join  prod_patent pt using(patentid) 
inner Join  prods p using(productid)  
where(qty - iqty) > 0 
order by 
     p.productid,p.product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add table aliase with field "product"

select 
    distinct on (productid)p.product,
    pb.productid, 
    pb.mrp,
    pb.ptr,
    pb.ssr,
    pt.patent
from  prod_batch pb
    inner Join  prod_patent pt using(patentid) 
    inner Join  prods p using(productid)  
where(qty - iqty) > 0 
order by 
    p.product
```